# How to get started with Blackberry programming in J2ME?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am new to Blackberry development and having problems getting started.

Could anyone guide me to relevant resources like tutorials and/or simple sample programs?

Comment: perhaps you should ask something specific?

Comment: To get started with BlackBerry development you can refer this [Getting stared with BlackBerry](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/30946/Creating_your_first_app_1806946_11.jsp)

Answer (score 3):

Start [here](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/blackberrydev/)

a tutorial with a general approach and a Hello World code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

or if you are already familiar with J2ME programming in general, Polish supports some parts of the BlackBerry API, too. See [here.](http://www.j2mepolish.org/cms/leftsection/documentation/platforms/blackberry.html)

Answer (score 0):

When I'm starting my Blackberry development for the first time, I'm *downloading all samples* in the Blackberry Developer site, and load in my Eclipse (with Blackberry Java plugin 1.3)

If you are using Eclipse with Blackberry Java Plugin as the editor too, you can go to menu
**Blackberry** > **Import** > **Blackberry Samples**

It should download all blackberry samples that you can review and learn, including the simple Hello World application demo.

If you are using Blackberry JDE, after install, go to the installation directory, you will find "samples" folder. you can get all the samples too.