# black berry basic learning program

Tags: blackberry

I am new in BB domain and I am working as a trainee programmer. Can you please suggest some basic programs?

Comment: How about the program that was linked to in an answer to a [very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107680/how-to-get-started-with-blackberry-programming-in-j2me) of yours yesterday? Maybe you can explain in more detail what you are looking for as it seems that this answer didn't fulfill your needs?

Answer (score 1):

Start here : http://ezinearticles.com/?BlackBerry-Programming-101---How-to-Get-Started-With-BlackBerry-Software-Development&id=432477

Answer (score 0):

Visit http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/?userType=21